# Mysql triggers dont work

Tags: mysql, triggers, syntax-error

I have been searching all around about TRIGGERS since I am in dire needs for some of them, but it doesn't matter how much I try **Mysql workbench 6.3 CE** won't allow me to create it. It seems like my server is 5.7 and I have read the manual for references but I still can't make them to work.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER updateproductostock
BEFORE INSERT ON producto
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
NEW.prod_points = prod_price / 2;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I have a table named *producto* which has id, description, price, stock and points. What I want to do is to have the points value to be the half of the price value. So if the price of a product is $100 then the points value will be 50.

I cant create the trigger, mysql gives me syntax error.

I also would like to make a trigger in which the stock value of *producto* depends on the table *order*. *Order* has an order id, product id, description and quantity. So when I insert a new order I want to have the value of stock in *producto* to change. If an *order* is made with the same id of the product then I want the quantity of the order to be added to the stock of the *product*.

Again, mysql gives me syntax error.

I have searched all over the place and tried different kinds of syntax but I get error. My mysql does have the option for trigger.

Or perhaps is there an easier way to do what i want to do? Please help

Answer (score 0):

For the sql you've shown, I would guess `prod_price / 2` should be `NEW.prod_price / 2`.

For the latter issue, the trigger needs to be on the order table; but it is generally frowned on maintaining such values when they should be easily calculable unless there is a pressing performance reason to do so. My guess with your problems with that would be that your order table is named with a keyword and you are forgetting to delimit it properly with `.

Comment: it is frowned upon? So is there a better way? Stored procedures?

Comment: The frowned upon part is storing such aggregated values in the first place. It's one thing if you're running a large database that needs to run VERY frequent queries on such data, and are properly managing the risk of the data becoming inconsistent; but otherwise you're opening yourself up to the possibility of inconsistent data for the benefit of avoiding _writing_ a few queries like this `SELECT ..., SUM(c) FROM a JOIN b ON a.id = b.a_id GROUP BY ...` ...but if you are going to maintain such values, triggers are probably one of the most reliable ways (as long as they're never disabled.)